# The expression x(start_point($geometry)) doesn't return anything, how can I fix it?

Tags: fields-attributes, coordinates, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to get the coordinates of start and end of lines in a layer, but the expression `x(start_point($geometry))` doesn't return anything, what's wrong?

Here's my code:

```
capa = "//atlantico2/ACTIVOS/0702 - EIA LINEA DE CONEXION ELECTRICA PA/04 Elaboracion/02 Ambiental/05 SIG/01 GDB/SHP/BIOTICO/ParcelasVirtuales_LN.shp"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(capa,'','ogr')
fields = layer.fields()

camposNuevos = ['X_Ini','Y_Ini','X_Fin','Y_Fin']
indices = []
for field in fields:
    for campo in camposNuevos:
        if field.name() == campo:
            indice = layer.fields().indexFromName(campo)
            indices.append(indice)
layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes(indices)
layer.updateFields()

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('X_Ini',QVariant.Double),QgsField('Y_Ini',QVariant.Double),
QgsField('X_Fin',QVariant.Double),QgsField('Y_Fin',QVariant.Double)])
layer.updateFields()

exp = QgsExpression("'x(start_point($geometry))'")
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(\
QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        f['X_Ini'] = exp.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(capa,'','ogr')
```

And this is the attribute table with the field needed in Zeros:

[image: Field X_Ini in Zeros]

I'm using Qgis 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
exp = QgsExpression('x(start_point($geometry))')
context = QgsExpressionContext()

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        exp.prepare(context)
        value = exp.evaluate(context)
        f['X_Ini'] = value
        layer.updateFeature(f)

iface.addVectorLayer(capa,'someName','ogr')
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, it worked.

Comment: @ZamirEstebanCajamarcaLópez - Most welcome, glad it helped :).